# jQuery QuickSearch

Tags: jquery, quick-search

1. The filtering action runs on keypressed is there a way to make it
   run by a button. (i.e. the table is not filter unless a button is
   pressed). This will help in many ways especially on huge tables or
   when working on multiple tables.
2. There are 2 ways on filtering (all columns or using tag) what if we
   were able to filter according to the column name.

   ```
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td name="col1">Column 1 Row 1</td> 
        <td name="col2">Column 2 Row 1</td> 
        <td name="col3">Column 3 Row 1</td> 
        <td name="col4">Column 4 Row 1</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td name="col1">Column 1 Row 2</td> 
        <td name="col2">Column 2 Row 2</td> 
        <td name="col3">Column 3 Row 2</td> 
        <td name="col4">Column 4 Row 2</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td name="col1">Column 1 Row 3</td> 
        <td name="col2">Column 2 Row 3</td> 
        <td name="col3">Column 3 Row 3</td> 
        <td name="col4">Column 4 Row 3</td> 
     </tr>
   </table>
   ```
3. Each time entering a new word in the input box reset the table then
   apply the filtering on all records. What if there is a way to give
   the option of filtering all the records or just the result of
   previously filtered. I tried this by making the following changes in
   your example:

   ```
       $('input#id_search').quicksearch('table#table.myQS tbody tr');
       $('input#id_search2').quicksearch('table#table.myQS tbody tr');
   ```

   Then entering a word in "id_search" then another word in
   "id_search2" which filtered the result of the first filtering
   action.
4. Is there a way to get the count of filtered records (rows) in the
   header or footer of each table?
5. How to make on after run an external function (i.e. function found
   in .js file).
6. Where can i get a documentation for Quicksearch plugin ? as there
   are methods isn't mentioned in the example (i.e. using a class
   instead of ID).